# AngularJS multiplication not working for VAT

Tags: angularjs-directive

I've got some simple Angular maths going on.
My subtotal input field adds the various fields together fine.  Unfortunately the VAT is not getting calculated.

If however I name the subtotal input field like so ng-model="invoice.SubTotal" and type a new amount into the subtotal field the VAT works correctly but then the addition fails.

I'm obviously making a very simple mistake but I just can't get them to add and * the VAT

Any help most appreciated.

```
              <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Line Cost</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="invoice.LineCost" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Note Cost</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="invoice.NoteCost" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Disposal Cost</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="invoice.DisposalCost" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Transport Cost</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="invoice.TransportCost" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Site Work</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="invoice.SiteWork" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Demurrage</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="invoice.Demurrage" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Sub Total</label>
                    <input type="number"  class="form-control"   ng-value="(invoice.LineCost + invoice.NoteCost + invoice.DisposalCost + invoice.TransportCost + invoice.SiteWork + invoice.Demurrage) " />
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>VAT</label>
                    <input type="number" disabled class="form-control" ng-value="((invoice.SubTotal * 1.2)  - invoice.SubTotal).toFixed(2)" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Total</label>
                    <input type="number" disabled class="form-control" ng-value="(invoice.SubTotal * 1.2).toFixed(2)" />
                </div>
```

Comment: What output are you getting?  You might be casting your numbers as strings when you add them in which case 2+2 = 22 instead of 4.

Comment: My outbound is fine 100 + 100 = 200  The issue is the VAT is ignored if I don't add  ng-model="invoice.SubTotal" (makes sense)  If I add ng-model="invoice.SubTotal" then the addition fails : (